# How to keep the selected value from the dropdown when the page is changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I am working on a project in C# (using mvc) and I had to make a dropdown filter in my view with only two choices: `Yes` and `No`.

Here is the code that populates the dropdown:

Service method:

```
public List<SelectListItem> cancelledForDp()
{
    List<SelectListItem> cancelled = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var data = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1",Text = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "NULL",Text = "No" }
    };
    cancelled = data.ToList();
    return cancelled;
}
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.cancelledDp = utilService.cancelledForDp();
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cancelled", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cancelledDp, new { id = "chosenCancelled" })
```

The values in the column in the database table are: `"1"` and `NULL` (I mean the values connected with the filter). My filter works correctly.

When I filter with the value `No`, a few pages are returned. When I go to a different page than the first (2 or more), the value of the dropdown is not kept. It should be `No`, but instead it is `Yes`.

I searched for answers connected with my problem here, but did not find anything appropriate.

I guessed the problem is connected with `NULL` value so I tried this:

In the service:

```
public List<SelectListItem> cancelledForDp()
{
    List<SelectListItem> cancelled = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var data = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1",Text = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2",Text = "No" }
    };
    cancelled = data.ToList();
    return cancelled;
}
```

Controller:

```
if(cancelled == 2)
{
    cancelled = null;
}
```

But I got the same results. When I selected `No` in the filter and went to the second page, `Yes` was in the dropdown instead of `No`.

I debugged and found that the value of the parameter `cancelled` of the method in the controller is `null` when I went to the second page.

**How to keep the selected value from the dropdown when the page is changed?**

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generating `<option>` elements with values of `"1"` and `"NULL"`. The text `"NULL"` is not the same as `null` value (which is recognized by an empty string - i.e. it has no value). If the value of property `cancelled` is `null` then the first option will be selected because there is no option element with an empty value (and because something has to be selected)

In order for it to be selected, your element needs to be `<option value="">No</option>` which you can generate using either

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cancelledForDp()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1",Text = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "",Text = "No" }
    };
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cancelledForDp()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Yes" },
    };
}
```

and in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownList("cancelled", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cancelledDp, "No", new { id = "chosenCancelled" })
```

where the 3rd parameter creates the labelOption with a `null` value.

As a side note, if your field can only store 2 values, then you should be using as database `BIT` field so that the property is

```
public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
```

not `int? cancelled` (or is it `string cancelled`?)

and simply use

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCancelled)
```

in the view. I also recommend you always use the strongly typed `***For()` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried your suggestion: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cancelledForDp()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Yes" },
    };
} and

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("cancelled", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cancelledDp, "No", new { id = "chosenCancelled" }) and it solved my problem.